# Are there any non-discrete definitions for the size of a matrix?

Tags: matrices, vectors, tensors, multilinear-algebra

Throughout my math education I have noticed that in order to solve a difficult problem with one set of numbers it helps to move to a larger encompassing set. For example, subtracting some natural numbers, $\mathbb{N}$ , requires the integers,  $\mathbb{Z}$ (e.g. $3-4$ would be meaningless in a world with only the natural numbers). This pattern seems to continue, from the integers to the real numbers to the complex numbers. There also seems to be another pattern that holds with the idea of scalars to matrices to tensors, etc. Each next set holding (or generalizing) the previous.

What I have noticed--in my limited math education--is that matrices stick to natural numbers in their dimensionality. That is: $$i,j \in \mathbb{N},\mathbb{R}^{i\times j}$$

My question boils down to this:

1. Can matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{i\times j} : i,j \in \mathbb{C}$?
2. If not why not?
3. If so, then what does it mean for one of these objects to have a non-natural dimension? For example, a vector, $v \in \mathbb{R}^{- \pi/2 \times 1} $ or a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{0.5 \times -1} $? Is such an object even able to be represented?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^n$ is defined discretely as far as I know, so your question would perhaps be better put as "is there any non-discrete definition for the size of vectors"?

Comment: In physics there is a concept of matrices with _negative_ dimensions, it appears in the replica technique for spin glass theory.

Comment: @user619894 The dimension has to be a cardinality, but the possible values of indices might include negative numbers. It would help if you can link to more details of what you have in mind. But [Wikipedia's article on spin glass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_glass) only seems to mention "ordinary" matrices.

Comment: @J.G there is more to the internet besides wikipedia :) https://www.jstor.org/stable/3094789?seq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A perhaps related result to what you're after, if not a direct answer:

Given any two sets $P$ and $Q$, you can from the vector spaces $\mathbb{R}^P$ and $\mathbb{R}^Q$ consisting of all functions from $P$ (resp. $Q$) to $\mathbb{R}$. Then the matrices representing linear maps from $\mathbb{R^P} \to \mathbb{R}^Q$ are given by elements of $\mathbb{R}^{P \times Q}$: functions from $P \times Q \to \mathbb{R}$.

These vector spaces have dimension other than natural numbers (say, if $P$ and $Q$ are infinite) but they do not have dimensions like what you might be looking for: i.e. they are not "complex dimensional", etc.
Instead, these vector spaces can take [cardinal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number) as their dimension.

As far as a "continuous" analogue of dimension goes, I don't know of any reasonable way to make sense of a "vector space of dimension $\frac{1}{2}$", let alone one of dimension $2+i$. It also strikes me as unlikely that such a concept exists. That said, I haven't ever thought to look into such things, and I've been surprised before. Who knows, maybe you'll be the person to develop such a notion!

**Edit:**

After a short google, it looks like this *is* something that people have thought of before (at least for rational dimension), but the machinery is rather complex. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1466820/vector-spaces-with-fractional-dimension) for instance.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: The closest-but-no-cigar we can get is ["dimensions", but not of vector spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_dimension).

Comment: @J.G. - it seems a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71192/fractional-versions-of-euclidean-space) was answered with a discussion of Hausdorff Dimension... I agree with you, though -- this is close-but-no-cigar, and the linked answer seems to bear that out too.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$'s indices can be any complex numbers, $A$ becomes a linear operator that maps a function $f$ of domain $\Bbb C$ to $\int_{\Bbb C^2}A(x, \, y)f(y) dy$. This involves regarding each such function $f$ as a vector in a space of dimension $|\Bbb C|$.